# masterpage space around the edges

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm using masterpage in asp.NET (vs express 2015) and everything is working fine, but the look of it when run in a browser is annoying; there is a space arround the edges. It isn't a serious problem, but I was wondering if there is a solution for that.
[a caption of my web application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynmR1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its basically the default margin applied at the body element, you can override it as bellow.

```
body{
    margin:0px !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried it and the space became smaller, but didn't disapear. it looks better though so thx

Comment: You'll need to inspect the page body or other element to find what is causing the issue. If you are using Firfox then see the detail on following URL to find inspect an element https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Comment: I'm using Chrome

Comment: Do some RnD on inspect element. In Chrome press Ctrl + Sft + I and go to styles tab. it will look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5k3U.png